# Activities `list` endpoint doesn't appear to return all activities

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am making requests to the YouTube Data API's Activity `list` endpoint for another user's channel, using the `nextPageToken` in each response to try to eventually reach the first Activity that the user ever posted to their channel. The channel has been around for about six years, so there are plenty of records to go through. I am requesting 50 records per page, and the requests do seem to return with the correct results.

The problem is, the endpoint isn't returning the earliest Activity on the user's channel. The earliest record it returns was submitted about three years ago, so that's a lot of content that's missing.

Does the API have some sort of built-in limit to how old an Activity can be for it to be returned, or could this be an artifact from an API change, i.e. all videos uploaded more than 3 years ago aren't considered "activities" and so won't be returned?